# Djangoのチェックボックスをmaterializecssの形に合わせて出力したい

Tags: python, django

お世話になっております。
以下のサイトを参考にサイトを作成しております。
http://qiita.com/kaki_k/items/511611cadac1d0c69c54

Djangoのチェックボックスをmaterializecssの形に合わせて出力したいです。
デフォルトで出力するとlabelの中にinputが含まれていますが、labelとinputを分離するにはどのように修正すればよいでしょうか。

materializecssのチェックボックスは以下
http://materializecss.com/forms.html

## 現状ソースコード

### [model.py]

```
from django.db import models

class Actress(models.Model):
ITEM = (
    (1, 'test1'),
    (2, 'test2'),
    (3, 'test3'),
)
item = models.IntegerField('アイテム', null=True, default=None, choices=ITEM)
```

### [forms.py]

```
from django import forms
from cms.models import Actress

class ActressForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Actress
        fields = ('item')
```

### [html]

```
<form class="col s12" action="{% url 'cms:actress_add' %}" method="post" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            {% for value in form.item %}
                <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ forloop.counter }}" />
                    <label for="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ value }}</label>
                </p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
</form>
```

## 現状出力コード

```
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="1">
<label for="1">
    <label for="id_item_0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="1" id="id_item_0">test1
    </label>
</label>
</p>
```

## 理想の出力コード

```
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="1">
<label for="1">test1</label>
</p>
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/90408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML側を以下のように書き換えて解決しました。

{% csrf_token %}
            
                {% for key, value in form.item.field.choices %}

{{ value }}

{% endfor %}